# My Dell XPS machine shuts down once it is starting training with Titan X GPU in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I have an Dell XPS machine, which was working fine with Nvidia 1080 GPU card. I had to change the GPU to TITAN X. But the problem is that once it is starting to train, it is switching off the system because of the power. I have heard from one of friends that there is a command on ubuntu that you can change/decrease the power of system whilw you are training the deep network by Titan X. I Googled, but I could not find it. If you know, please help.

Thank you

Comment: You’re looking for a software fix to a hardware problem. If the machine is shutting itself off you have something wrong with the hardware. Software can’t fix hardware.

Comment: The fix is to upgrade your power supply.

Comment: @Appleoddity there is a command in ubuntu that changes the level of power, I am looking for that. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the command, you can change the power level of GPU by running the following command:

```
sudo nvidia-smi -pl 150
```

The command changes the power level to 150W.